# Convert multiples xml nodes data into varchar

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, nodes

I want to convert an xml string like this :

```
'<orga_label>ORG1</orga_label><orga_label>ORG2</orga_label><orga_label>ORG3</orga_label>'
```

into a varchar like this :

```
'ORG1, ORG2, ORG3'
```

in t-sql in one query.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is it a variable or a column please?

Comment: Also, this is not correct XMl without a root node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep is very simple and avoid XML methods here...

```
DECLARE @foo xml = '<orga_label>ORG1</orga_label><orga_label>ORG2</orga_label><orga_label>ORG3</orga_label>';

SELECT
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), @foo), '</orga_label><orga_label>', ', '
        ), 
        '<orga_label>', ''
      ),
      '</orga_label>', ''
    );
```

Edit: this has the advantage of not invoking the XML methods and processor.

Answer (score 0):

It's better you use a xml parser in script language like ruby .

```
require 'rexml/document'
xml =REXML::Document.new(File.open"filename/filename.XML")
xml.each_element('//(your element)') do |sdobi|
   puts sdobi.attributes["orga_label"]
end
```

If you really want to use sql, it's a little bit comeplex:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( columnname, LOCATE( '<orga_label',columnname ) +12, LOCATE( '</', tablename) )  from tablename
```

the if the substring not right try to change the number

Comment: LOCATE is not a T-SQL function and whan I use CHARINDEX.
The result is not OK : 

BPACA</orga_label>

I can't use other language to make that because I use a framework. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @xml xml = '<orga_label>ORG1</orga_label><orga_label>ORG2</orga_label><orga_label>ORG3</orga_label>';

select stuff((select 
    ',' + s from (
    select 
    a.b.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') s
    from @xml.nodes('/orga_label') a(b)
) t
for xml path('')
),1,1,'');
```